# Change/Convert type of xmlChar in C

Tags: c, xml, type-conversion, int, libxml2

I am currently reading in a 'starttime' atrribute from an xml file e.g "20190219085500" which I am storing in an xmlChar variable.

I am also reading in a 'duration' attribute also as an xmlChar which is the amount of seconds the program is on for e.g. "1500" (25 mins)

What I am trying to do is create another attribute 'finishtime' for when the program will finish which is essentially, 'starttime' + 'duration'

I'm just unsure on how to go about this problem, weather it is converting the xmlChar's to int or if there another way.

I am writting in C btw :) Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of e.g. `"20190219085500"`? You can't solve your problem without being able to answer that.

Comment: And I doubt you store the whole string in a *single* `xmlChar` variable, but rather using arrays or pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah pointers mate, and 20190219085500 is in a date/time format -> yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss

Answer (score 0):

While there are no standard C functions to convert strings to a time-stamp directly, many implementations have a function called `strptime` that parses strings into a [`tm` structure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) from which you can [get a timestamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) which usually is in seconds since an epoch.

Then [converting the "duration" to an integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) is easy, and adding it to the timestamp is even easier.

Lastly you can use [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) to convert the new timestamp back into a `tm` structure, which you can pass to [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) to get a string-representation of the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks this is making a bit more sense now, any chance of a code example?